# Repeat multiple rows in a table with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to create a table in AngularJS which has multiple rows per item. The output needs to be similar to:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Item 1 Row a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item 1 Row b</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item 1 Row c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item 1 Row d</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item 2 Row a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item 2 Row b</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item 2 Row c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item 2 Row d</td></tr>
</table>
```

What would be the best way of achieving this? Is there an approach I can take that requires markup like this:

```
<table>
    <tag ng-repeat="item in data">
        <tr><td>Item {{item.id}} Row a</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Item {{item.id}} Row b</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Item {{item.id}} Row c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Item {{item.id}} Row d</td></tr>
    </tag>
</table>
```

EDIT:
`data` will be along these lines:

```
{"data": [
     {
         "id": 1
     },
     {
         "id": 2
     },
     {
         "id": 3
     }
 ]}
```

Comment: what about another ng-repeat? `<td ng-repeat="x in ['a','b','c','d']">Item {{item.id}} Row {{x}}</td>`

Comment: Sorry, I've just realised I made a typo in the second code block there. Each `<td>` should have been in a different row. Editing it now

Comment: What's in `data`?

Comment: Its is an array of json object. Have edited the question to demonstrate

Comment: can you clear more with your code or output you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the `tag` with `tbody` like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="item in data">
        <tr><td>Item {{item.id}} Row a</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Item {{item.id}} Row b</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Item {{item.id}} Row c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Item {{item.id}} Row d</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This will work.

Your table will have multiple `tbody` tags if that isn't an issue.

Comment: Thats perfect! Thank you